# How to align/ orient a progress bar to be vertical in a tool strip?

Tags: winforms, c#-3.0

When i add a progress bar to tool strip, it is horizontal. How to align/ orient a progress bar to be vertical in a tool strip which is inside a tool strip container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WinForms ProgressBar does not draw in a vertical orientation. As the ToolStrip progress bar is internally using the standard ProgressBar this is why there is no property/method for changing its orientation.